# Grails Portlets for Liferay

Tags: grails, portlet

I'm actively developing grails portlets for liferay till today .
**I was wondering is there a future road map for next plugin releases and updates for portlet support**, because i was not finding people developing portlet applications on grails on net.

Is there any portlet applications running under production ?? .

could any one please provide links if any ?

thanks,
srinath

Answer (score 0):

I'm not working on the plugin any more, maybe the new maintainers will see this and comment on their plans.

If the plugin is useful to you, I strongly encourage you to get involved and improve it.

cheers

Lee

Comment: thanks lee, I'm still a newbie and directly working on portlets . My intention is to just know is there are any portlet applications available ?

Comment: I haven't developed any, maybe try asking on the mailing list. I presume Kenji or Michael might have some running in Production by now.